# c# foreach не корректно работает с массивом CheckBox?

Tags: c#

Выходит исключение в виде названия данного портала, при отладке он бесконечно бегает внутри foreach с 1-м элементом, не переходя к остальным. С чем это связанно?

```
 public void GenerateView(ref CheckBox cb)
    {
        CheckBox[] CB = new CheckBox[] { CBZPI,CBZFI,CBBrakM,CBBrakW };

        foreach (CheckBox cbt in CB)
        {
            cbt.Checked = false;
            if (cbt == cb)
                cbt.Checked=true;

        }
```

Comment: if (cbt == cb) никогда не будет равен, что вы пытаетесь сравнить?

Comment: Может быть передавать Checkbox.Name параметром для сравнения? void Foo(string name) { CheckBox[] CB = new Checkbox[]{...}; foreach(var cbt in CB) { cbt.Checked = cbt.Name == name; } }

Comment: Я передаю туда ссылку на CheckBox полагаю? 

` private void CBZFI_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox tb = (CheckBox)sender;
            GenerateView(ref tb);
        }
`
Можно, но принципиально хочу разобраться в работе с объектами. 
+ даже если и так, и он бы никогда равным не был, что ему мешает перейти на следующую итерацию, у меня же не while

Comment: Как в комментарии код нормально писать?)

Comment: А, всё, по ходу понял, я этой строчкой
 cbt.Checked = false;
 вызываю обработчик CBZFI_CheckedChanged. Не знал что это так работает)

Comment: Тогда другой вопрос, можно ли на время выполнения метода отключить этот обработчик?)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите реализовать нечто такое...

[image: пример работы]

Используйте для сравнения значение свойства `Tag`.
Для наглядности я создаю чекбоксы в коде, но вы вольны их создать в дизайнере, только не забудьте назначить всем чекбоксам нужные значения свойства `Tag`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly string _tagDog = "Dog";
    private readonly string _tagCat = "Cat";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Пример";

        //добавляем в коде чексбоксы
        AddTypeAnimalsCheckboxes();
        AddAnimalsCheckboxes();
    }

    private void AddTypeAnimalsCheckboxes()
    {
        int startY = 33;
        int delta = 20;

        var checkBoxDogs = new CheckBox
        {
            Name = "checkBoxDogs",
            Tag = _tagDog, //!
            Text = "Собаки",
            Height = 17,
            Width = 70,
            Location = new Point(x: 34, y: startY)
        };

        var checkBoxCats = new CheckBox
        {
            Name = "checkBoxCats",
            Tag = _tagCat, //!
            Text = "Кошки",
            Height = 17,
            Width = 70,
            Location = new Point(x: 34, y: startY + delta)
        };

        checkBoxDogs.CheckedChanged += CheckBoxAnimal_CheckedChanged;
        checkBoxCats.CheckedChanged += CheckBoxAnimal_CheckedChanged;

        groupBoxTypeAnimal.Controls.Add(checkBoxDogs);
        groupBoxTypeAnimal.Controls.Add(checkBoxCats);
    }

    private void AddAnimalsCheckboxes()
    {
        int startY = 33;
        int delta = 20;

        var checkBoxDog1 = new CheckBox
        {
            Name = "checkBoxDog1",
            Tag = _tagDog, //!
            Text = "Шарик",
            Height = 17,
            Width = 70,
            Location = new Point(x: 36, y: startY)
        };

        var checkBoxCat1 = new CheckBox
        {
            Name = "checkBoxCat1",
            Tag = _tagCat, //!
            Text = "Мурзик",
            Height = 17,
            Width = 70,
            Location = new Point(x: 36, y: startY + delta)
        };

        var checkBoxDog2 = new CheckBox
        {
            Name = "checkBoxDog2",
            Tag = _tagDog,
            Text = "Мухтар",
            Height = 17,
            Width = 70,
            Location = new Point(x: 36, y: startY + delta * 2)
        };

        var checkBoxCat2 = new CheckBox
        {
            Name = "checkBoxCat2",
            Tag = _tagCat,
            Text = "Барсик",
            Height = 17,
            Width = 70,
            Location = new Point(x: 36, y: startY + delta * 3)
        };

        groupBoxAnimals.Controls.Add(checkBoxDog1);
        groupBoxAnimals.Controls.Add(checkBoxCat1);
        groupBoxAnimals.Controls.Add(checkBoxDog2);
        groupBoxAnimals.Controls.Add(checkBoxCat2);
    }

    private void CheckBoxAnimal_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = sender as CheckBox;

        foreach (CheckBox cb in groupBoxAnimals.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
        {
            //ищем по совпадению со значением Tag
            if (cb.Tag == checkBox.Tag)
            {
                cb.Checked = checkBox.Checked;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну не совсем так, мне нужно чтобы я выбрал кошку, и при этом все собаки, ослики и коровы пропали. Ну ваш код не сложно уже изменить под это,спасибо, я одного не пойму, почему в моём варианте изменение свойства "Checked" самовызывает обработчик события "CheckedChanged" и из-за этого зацикливается, а в вашем нет?